# Incorrect GNU Octave 3D Plot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, octave

I was trying to draw four points in 3D using GNU Octave. So I began by defining them first.

```
a = [1 2 3];
b = [-1 0 -1];
c = [5 4 3];
d = [1 0 -2];
```

Next, I tried with `plot3(a,b,c,d, 'o')` but I quickly abandoned the idea. Instead I rather used two times `plot3` function dividing it with `hold on`.

```
plot3(a,b,'o')
hold on
plot3(c,d);
```

And here's what happened:[image]
Instead of four points this figure depicts 6 points which are coplanar.

Can somebody please explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [**the documentation**](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html#index-plot3) very clearly states, the inputs to the function are the `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinates. If arrays are used, a single point is created for each corresponding point in these vectors. In your case, each input that you are providing to `plot3` has *three elements* and is therefore going to create *three points*. Since you are calling `plot3` twice like this, the result is going to be `6` points.

The *correct* usage of `plot3` would be to put all of your `x` values in an array, `y` values in an array, and `z` values in an array.

```
plot3([a(1), b(1), c(1), d(1)], [a(2), b(2), c(2), d(2)], [a(3), b(3), c(3), d(3)], 'o')
```

Or maybe more concisely

```
points = [a; b; c; d];
plot3(points(:,1), points(:,2), points(:,3), 'o');
```

Comment: I've tested your solution and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much for your time and efford!

Answer (score 3):

If you read the help text of `plot3`, you will find:

```
 -- plot3 (X, Y, Z)
 -- plot3 (X, Y, Z, FMT)
 -- plot3 (X, CPLX)
 -- plot3 (CPLX)
```

You are calling `plot3` with the form `plot3 (X, CPLX)` which says:

```
 If only two arguments are given, as

      plot3 (X, CPLX)

 the real and imaginary parts of the second argument are used as the
 Y and Z coordinates, respectively.
```

What you should be doing is to call `plot3` with the form `plot3 (X, Y, Z, FMT)`. Also, you can do all of that with a single call to `plot3`, no need for `hold on` and add new points.  Like so:

```
a = [ 1  2  3];
b = [-1  0 -1];
c = [ 5  4  3];
d = [ 1  0 -2];
p = [a; b; c; d];
plot3 (p(:,1), p(:,2), p(:,3), "o")
```

Comment: Informative answer, but I read @Suever's answer first. I'm still upvoting though. Thank you so much for answering anyway!